# R Testing Simple Effects Using testInteractions() Not working for Mixed ANOVA

Tags: r, anova, repeated-measures, interaction, effects

I am trying to use the R phia package to test Simple Effects for a mixed ANOVA.
It works fine if there is no term for the within subject factor:

```
model1=aov(value ~ predictor1*predictor2, data=myData)
library(phia)
testInteractions(model1, fixed = "predictor1", across = "predictor2")
```

However, if I include an error term for the within subject factor, it throws an error:

```
model2=aov(value ~ predictor1*predictor2 + Error(participant/predictor2), data=myData)
library(phia)
testInteractions(model2, fixed = "predictor1", across = "predictor2")
```

> Error in [.data.frame(model.frame(model), predictors) :
> undefined columns selected

Answer (score 1):

I've had a kind email from the package creator, who recommends creating the models with "lme4" instead with the "aov" function. I'll update this post if I am successful.

**EDIT:** Yes, with lme4 it works:

```
model3=lmer(value ~ predictor1*predictor2 + (1|participant), data=myData, REML=FALSE)
library(phia)
testInteractions(model3, fixed = "predictor1", across = "predictor2")
```